# var_dump or print_r is not able to print variable in console in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have used both var_dump and print_r in my laravel(5.4) code. But none of them is able to print the output . only error_message print the message. What should I do to make var_dump and print_r working?

Comment: try dd(), it will print and exit

Comment: What I want here is I want to print the variable but I do not want to exit the execution